# Which of the following sentences is correct: Can you not travel during this period? or Are you unable to travel during this period?

Tags: grammar, british-english, modal-verbs

I came across the following sentence written by a supposedly native (British) English speaker in a text I'm currently editing and it immediately struck me as being odd:

- *We offer special discounts to people traveling with their pets during the holiday season. Can you not travel with your pet during this period?*

Is "Can you not" used correctly in this sentence, knowing that the writer was supposed to convey the meaning that someone cannot travel/is unable to travel during the period concerned?

Unless I'm mistaken, "can you not" normally conveys the meaning of a request to do something or rather not do something, i.e. "please do not travel during this period". Wouldn't it be more accurate to say "Are you unable to travel during this period?" Is"can you not" as it is used here an instance of dialectal or regional variation (e.g. typical British usage) I am not aware of?

Comment: The quote looks strange because the sentences seem too disparate to place next to each other like this. Also, Brits would still usually spell 'traveling' 'travelling'.

Comment: _Can you not_ is normally contracted to _can't you_, just as _you cannot_ is normally contracted to _you can't_. Both full forms are extremely formal and bring attention to themselves and their speakers. _Can't you travel during this period?_ is perfectly ordinary and means the same as _Are you unable_.

Comment: All sorts of uneducated people try to write copy these days. This is just nonsense.

Comment: ELU is not the best place for proofreading other people's work, but I think I figured out what's really wrong here. It should be "Can you not travel __without__ your pet durnig this period?" Of course things would be clearer with the context of the rest of the text beforehand. We don't really know the situation. The answer to your title question is "Yes they are both correct but it depends on the context."

Comment: Thank you all for your useful comments and answers to my question, which I can use to provide concrete feedback to the agency that wrote the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"can you not," is a British English, albeit somewhat archaic dialectal pattern.  Ashworth is correct that the spelling  “traveling” implies the advertisement is not British (“travelling” would be).  In America, the word honor, versus British honour.  The change in spelling, only occurs if the speaker/writer catches themselves, or another points it out.

The phrase is used like this:  Can you not call her?  With the emphasis on the word not.  The sentences do look strange placed side by side.  The first is an advertisement (business). Followed by the second sentence, asking a personal and challenging question (inappropriate usage for business). It is a 2021 advertisement attempting to be personal.

Comment: verses -> versus